# I get this error in next.js: Warning: Received NaN for the `children` attribute. If this is expected, cast the value to a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working on my first Next.js project and have a file `myCart.js` page. The code of which is given below:

```
function orderCard(arr1) {
  return (
    <>
      <div className={styles.item_group} key={arr1._id}>
        <OrderCard
          id={arr1._id}
          item={arr1.itemName}
          menu={String(arr1.menuId)}
          img={arr1.itemPic}
          summary={arr1.summary}
          size={String(arr1.itemSize)}
          qtty={String(arr1.qtty)}
          price={String(arr1.itemPrice)}
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

let noRefresh;
function makeGetRequest() {
  noRefresh = 'Please do not refresh';

  [arr1, setArr1] = useState(['']);
  [customerName, setCustomerName] = useState('');
  [customerMail, setCustomerMail] = useState('');
  [jwtokenCart, setJjwtokenCart] = useState('');

  axios.get('/api/users/myCart').then((resp) => {
    if (resp.data.status === 'success') {
      setArr1(resp.data.myList);
      setCustomerName(resp.data.userName);
      setCustomerMail(resp.data.userMail);
      setJjwtokenCart(resp.data.jwtoken);
      data = resp.data;
    } else alert('Something went wrong. Refresh the browser and try again');
  });

  function handleCheckout(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.target.textContent = 'Processing...';
  }

  const arrLen = arr1.length;
  const qttyTotal = arr1.reduce(
    (totalQtty, arrQty) => totalQtty + arrQty.qtty,
    0
  );

  const amtTotal = arr1.reduce((prev, curr) => {
    return prev + curr.qtty * curr.itemPrice;
  }, 0);

  return (
    <div>
      <Layout title="My Cart">
        <Link href="/">
          <a className={styles.toHome}>&larr; Back to home </a>
        </Link>
        <div className={styles.noRefresh}>{noRefresh}</div>
        <div>
          <div className={styles['customer-details']}>
            <h3 className={styles.cartName}>Cart of {customerName}</h3>
            <p className={styles['customer-details']}>{customerMail}</p>
          </div>
          <Container className={styles.container}>
            <section className={styles.section_cartList}>
              {/* <div className={styles.row0}> */}
              <div className={`${styles['col_1_of_2']} ${styles['col-1']}`}>
                <div className={`${styles['grid']} ${styles['menu-item']}`}>
                  {arr1.map(orderCard)}
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className={`${styles['col_1_of_2']} ${styles['col-2']}`}>
                <div className={styles.heading}>
                  <h2
                    className={styles.heading_secondary}
                    id={styles.heading_secondary}
                  >
                    SUMMARY
                  </h2>
                  <h3 className={styles.itemsTotalP}>No. of items</h3>
                  <h3 className={styles.itemsTotal}>{arrLen}</h3>
                  <h3 className={styles.qttyTotalP}>No. of dishes</h3>
                  <h3 className={styles.qttyTotal}>{qttyTotal}</h3>
                  <h3 className={styles.amtTotalP}>Total amount (US$):</h3>
                  <h3 className={styles.amtTotal}>{amtTotal}</h3>
                </div>
                <button
                  className={`${styles['label']} ${styles['btnCart']}`}
                  type="button"
                  onClick={handleCheckout}
                >
                  CHECKOUT
                </button>
              </div>
            </section>
          </Container>
        </div>
      </Layout>
    </div>
  );
}

export default makeGetRequest;
export { jwtokenCart, customerName };
```

```
<OrderCard

let cartId;
function OrderCard(props) {
  const removeFromCart = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.target.textContent = 'Processing...';
    cartId = props.id;
    if (cartId) {
      await axios.delete('/api/cart/' + cartId).then((res) => {
        if (res.data.status === 'success') {
          setTimeout(() => {
            Router.reload();
          }, 1000);
        } else {
          e.target.textContent = 'ERROR: Please try again';
          setTimeout(() => {
            e.target.textContent = 'REMOVE';
          }, 2000);
        }
      });
    }
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Card className={styles.card}>
        <Card.Title className={styles.dish_title}>
          <h3 className={styles.itemName} value={props.item}>
            {props.item}
          </h3>
          <p className={styles.menuId} value={props.menu}>
            MenuId: {props.menu}
          </p>
        </Card.Title>
        <Card.Img
          variant="top"
          className={styles.dish_photo}
          value={props.img}
          src={props.img}
        />
        <Card.Body className={styles.card_body}>
          <p className={styles.summary} value={props.summary}>
            {props.summary}
          </p>
          <h4 className={styles.dishSizeP}>Dish size (oz) :</h4>
          <h4 className={styles.dishSize} value={props.size}>
            {props.size}
          </h4>
          <h4 className={styles.dishQtyP}>Quantity :</h4>
          <h4 className={styles.dishQty} value={props.qtty}>
            {props.qtty}
          </h4>
          <h4 className={styles.dishPriceP}>Unit Price (US$) :</h4>
          <h4 className={styles.dishPrice} value={props.price}>
            {props.price}
          </h4>
          <hr className={styles.rule} />
          <h3 className={styles.subTotalP}>Sub Total (US$)</h3>
          <h3 className={styles.subTotal}>{props.qtty * props.price}</h3>
          <button
            className={`${styles['label']} ${styles['btnCart']}`}
            type="button"
            onClick={removeFromCart}
          >
            REMOVE
          </button>
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
    </>
  );
}
export default OrderCard;
```

Whenever the page is rendered I get following warning:

> Warning: Received NaN for the `children` attribute. If this is expected, cast the value to a string.
> at h3
> at div
> at CardBody (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-bootstrap/esm/createWithBsPrefix.js:31:27)
> at div
> at Card (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-bootstrap/esm/Card.js:44:23)
> at OrderCard (webpack-internal:///./components/OrderCard.js:77:24)
> at div
> at div
> at div
> at section
> at div
> at Container (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-bootstrap/esm/Container.js:18:23)
> at div
> at div
> at div
> at div
> at Layout (webpack-internal:///./components/Layout.js:31:25)
> at div
> at makeGetRequest (webpack-internal:///./pages/myCart.js:75:73)
> at MyApp (webpack-internal:///./pages/_app.js:21:24)
> at ErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@next/react-dev-overlay/lib/internal/ErrorBoundary.js:23:47)
> at ReactDevOverlay (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@next/react-dev-overlay/lib/internal/ReactDevOverlay.js:73:23)
> at Container (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:146:5)
> at AppContainer (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:623:24)
> at Root (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:739:25)

I also get one more error on this page which is given below:

> Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of `makeGetRequest`. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.
> at makeGetRequest (webpack-internal:///./pages/myCart.js:75:73)
> at MyApp (webpack-internal:///./pages/_app.js:21:24)
> at ErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@next/react-dev-overlay/lib/internal/ErrorBoundary.js:23:47)
> at ReactDevOverlay (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@next/react-dev-overlay/lib/internal/ReactDevOverlay.js:73:23)
> at Container (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:146:5)
> at AppContainer (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:623:24)
> at Root (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:739:25)

It is pertinent to note that the project works fine in dev mode with these warnings, but not in prod mode or on deployment.

I tried lot of stuffs from documentation and also from suggestions to other developers in stackoverflow on similar issues. But none is working. I will appreciate help. Thank you. Regards

Comment: Can you add your `OrderCard` component to the question as well?

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply. I was not knowing that some response to my query has been by made. Yes I can surely add OrderCard. But I don't know how to append that file here. If you can guide me I will be obliged. Regards

Comment: I added the Order Card component. Awaiting guidance.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's your problem, but you should initialize arr1 as an empty array `[]`, not as an array with one empty string `['']`. Right now, on the first render you are calling `orderCard('')` which seems like it would cause issues like you are seeing.

Comment: It's most likely this line `<h3 className={styles.subTotal}>{props.qtty * props.price}</h3>` that's generating the error. Looks like `props.qtty * props.price` is generating a `NaN`, so you should render that as a string instead: ``{`${props.qtty * props.price}`}``.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue then I found my it was the float must be casted to string, my previous tag was

```
${targetCompany.currentPrice}
```

Then I changed to the following solve the warning:

```
${`${targetCompany.currentPrice}`}
```